# Editor config - how to align the code

Tags: visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I'm using VS Code and for formating my code I use a formatter `CTRL + SHIFT + I`. It works fine, but I would like to be able to format my code to be align in this way:

before:

`export const apiConfig = {
    protocol: 'https',
    url: 'www.example.com',
    timeoutSec: 15
}`

after:

`export const apiConfig = {
    protocol:   'https',
    url:        'www.example.com',
    timeoutSec: 15
}`

Any way to set it up? Any specific setting for .editorconfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible to easily achieve in one go within VScode and completely unrelated to `.editorconfig`, as it only governs rather [basic features](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties) — by design.

You will need to use the formatting in combination with an alignment plugin like this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steve8708.Align

If you feel adventurous, you may be able to hack together a solution which runs both commands in sequence at the push of a keyboard shortcut. However, VScode is not as readily scriptable in this regard as for example Vim is.