# Alignment: ignore operator-like characters like =, :, % in string literals (JS, VSCode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, alignment

***Edit:* This is related to [this alignment extension](https://github.com/annsk/vscode-alignment) and I think, that I should file an issue there.**

When you format your JavaScript and use operator characters in string literals, they will be handled as real operators.

I can show the result of an `align all chars` in VSCode with a small screen shot.

[image]

The format string for example should rather look like

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
```

This happens also a lot of times with Grunt template literals like

```
'<%= sSymlinkPath %>' -> alignment leads to '< % sSymlinkPath % >'
```

Is there any way to change the alignment configuration in order to let VSCose ignore operator-like characters in string literals? Or would it be a feature request?

I can use a [plugin as workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477315/2092322), but I'd also like to avoid this.

Comment: What's this "align all chars" command? (Seems fairly broken if it doesn't understand literals.) My fairly-standard install of vscode doesn't have it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ooh - you are so right. I will update my question.